# How to get rid of/resolve "invalid" status of emulator in DevEcoStudio

Tags: harmonyos, deveco-studio

In order to test any HMOS app in the emulator in DevEcoStudio IDE, we have to the emulator via Tools->Device Manager. Seldom, devices show "invalid" status due to which cannot launch the emulator. It stays in the same state for longer, sometimes for hours.

Is there any workaround for the above issue?
[image]

Thanks,
Kanak

Answer (score 1):

As the error popup says, currently All device instances are busy/in-use. So No device available at the moment.

There is no way we have to wait and try again later some time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, remote emulators do not work in some regions. Unfortunately there is no way around this.

Huawei is working to fix the problem, but I don't know the ETA.